# revolving background in rails w/ js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have 3 images I'd like to alternate as the background, this is the code I've written at the head and it doesn't seem to be working:

application.html.erb

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                  
var myImage = document.querySelectorAll(“.top-section neutral”);                                                                                              
var imageArray = ["../assets/images/background-girls.png”, “../assets/images/background-guys-game.png”, “../assets/images/background-neutral.png”];           
var imageIndex = 0;                                                                                                                                           
function changeImage () {                                                                                                                                     
    myImage.setAttribute(“src”, imageArray[imageIndex]);                                                                                                      
    imageIndex++;                                                                                                                                             
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {                                                                                                                    
    imageIndex = 0;                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                              
window.onload = function () {                                                                                                                                 
    setInterval(changeImage, 5000);                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                             
  </script>
```

I'm new to JS as a Ruby guy.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you are getting if any?

How many images match “.top-section neutral”?

Also the images you have in this array would need to load. Not to mention the img element itself that may not be loaded at window.onload.

More common practice is to have three images and alternate which is visible with css.

Edit:

You may be able to do something like:

```
<% @images.each do |image_src| %>
  <%= image_tag( image_src, class: "hidden rotate") %>
<% end %>
```

Then you could make sure your you have somewhere in your css saying something like

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Then you could use your javascript to alternate which .rotate image is not also .hidden.

Check out jquery's  .addClass/ .removeClass methods. also :nth-of-type(x)

As for alternating the index, there are a bunch of ways.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that sounds about right, especially "More common practice is to have three images and alternate which is visible with css." Being that I'm a newb, are there any guides that you can share on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is using the `image_path` from the [asset tag helpers](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path) instead of using the current asset path, so

```
var imageArray = ["<%= image_path('background-girls.png' %>", “<%= image_path('background-guys-game.png' %>", “<%= image_path('background-neutral.png' %>"];
```

Maybe that will solve your error

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have different quote marks in your imageArray (" versus the more curved version), that might be keeping your program from closing the strings correctly.